# How can I permanently apply this workaround to get the backlight working on an eMachines E525?

Tags: backlight

There is a display bug that I've been trying to find information on for a while now involving the "eMachines E525 Notebook computer" and it's "backlight", when using Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, and Kubuntu 11.04-11.10. Every time my computer gos to sleep the backlight gets shut off.

All I could find online was that I had to switch to the root of the system and edit the `/etc/rc.local` file, adding `setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00` before the `exit 0` at the end of the file. I did, and when I restart the computer I can see that the backlight is on, however when the computer gos to sleep or the lid gets closed, the backlight goes off and I have to open "Terminal" and type in `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00`.

I guess my real question is, is there a line of code I could enter into the grub menu or the `/etc/rc.local` file to make the backlight stay on? If anybody has any possible fixes for this bug, and would like to share the information with me, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a script in /etc/pm/sleep.d/ to run the command should work.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_backlight
```

copy/paste the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

# run 'setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00' when waking up

case "$1" in
        thaw|resume)
           setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
            ;;
esac
```

save and exit, then make it executable with

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_backlight
```

Comment: OK, I'll try it now.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I really appreciate the help, this was really the only issue I've ever had with Ubuntu. It was driving me mad.

Comment: Glad it helped. :~)

Comment: Thank you, but way it not fixed in relese 12.10? In canonical know about this problem?
Please confirm the problem to see it developers: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpid/+bug/392948